# Use observer with decorator in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, decorator

I tried to use observers with decorator syntax but it does not seem to work.

Without decorators:

```js
onRouteChange: observer('router.currentRouteName', function () {
  this.closeModal();
}),
```

Tried this with decorators (fails):

```
@observer('router.currentRouteName')
handler() {
  this.closeModal();
}
```

Error message:

> Assertion Failed: observer must be provided a function or an observer definition

I may have missed something but I did not found anything about decorators and observers in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember does not provide the decorator version of `observer` out of the box.

If your use case does not have a migration path you are happy with, you can use the [observer decorator from ember-decorators](https://ember-decorators.github.io/ember-decorators/docs/decorators#observers-and-events).

Make sure to read the [quickstart](https://ember-decorators.github.io/ember-decorators/docs) as it includes some information other than `ember install ember-decorators`.